# NSButton wont setFont: when layer backed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsbutton

I have my `NSButton` layer backed because I wanted to use a custom image, but this seems like it's inhibiting the use of the `setFont:` method when I need to programmatically change the font, as when I comment out the code for `wantsUpdateLayer:` and `updateLayer:`, `setFont:` works, but when the layer methods are in the code, it does nothing.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.fontChangeButton = [[CustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(82, 60, 190, 113)];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.fontChangeButton];
}

- (IBAction)changeFont:(id)sender {
    [self.fontChangeButton fontChange];
}
@end

@implementation CustomButton

- (void)fontChange{
    [self setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Dosis Bold" size:40]];
}

//when these are commented out, setFont: works, but I need them in for the custom button images
- (BOOL)wantsUpdateLayer{
    return YES;
}
- (void)updateLayer{
    if (self.state == NSOnState) {
        self.layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"buttonPressed.png"];
    }else
        self.layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"buttonUnpressed.png"];
}
```

This thread offers a workaround, but I'd much rather understand why this is happening and fix it: [Can't Change NSButton Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137881/cant-change-nsbutton-font)

Answer (score 0):

By overriding -wantsUpdateLayer to return YES you're bypassing calls to -drawRect:. This facility was introduced in 10.8 and exists for efficiency purposes.

There are two things I think should be clarified:

1 - You don't need to override -wantsUpdateLayer to be layer-backed. Just send -setWantsLayer:YES to your button to be layer-backed.

2 - In your example, creating a custom NSButtonCell class might be a better approach to what you're trying to do. Have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000730) on subclassing NSControl and this [how to](http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2010/05/06/drawing-custom-nsbutton-in-cocoa.html) to get started.

Comment: I will check out subclassing an NSButtonCell, but if I just use `-setWantsLayer:YES` instead of overriding `-wantsUpdateLayer:`, the `-updateLayer:` method never gets called, so the button does't draw with my custom images.

Comment: You can change how the background is drawn in the cell. If you are going to update the layer yourself this way, you’re going to end up drawing the whole button yourself. There’s no need for a custom layer to do a custom background.